# scheme function to filter predicate an alist

Tags: scheme, racket

I am supposed to write a function to filter and predicate an alist using scheme language. The problem is: "Write a function called (filter predicate alist) that takes an alist which is made of (name number) and returns all the arguments that their number is greater than 50. the greater than 50 part has to be another function which i've written below

```
(define (larger_than x)
   (if (> x 50) #t 
   #f))
```

I don't completely understand what i should do here.

Comment: `(filter larger_than alist)`

Comment: It appears that an example of an "alist" could be: `'( (name1 20) (name2 55) (name3 65) )`. It may be convenient to make the predicate work like: `(larger-than-50 '(name2 55))` => `#t`

Comment: @mnemenaut should i use "filter" in the code as well?

Comment: @TaRaNeH, the assignment appears to be to write two functions, with "filter" called as shown in Óscar López's comment. How the predicate function is defined will determine how the filter function has to work.

Comment: @TaRaNeH, question says: "an alist which is made of `(name number)`" - check that you understand how that differs from an alist with elements `(name . number)`

Comment: Note that `(if (> x 50) #t #f)` is more commonly written `(> x 50)`.

Answer (score 1):

> Write a function called (filter predicate alist) that takes an alist which is
> made of (name number) and returns all the arguments that their number is greater than 50.
> The greater than 50 part has to be another function.

Understanding the requirement:

1. develop a function `(define (filter predicate alist) ...)`
2. develop another function `(define (greater-than-50? ...) ...)`
3. an "alist" is a list of `(name number)` elements [1]
4. functions should be such that `(filter greater-than-50? alist)` produces a list of all elements of
   alist which have their number > 50

This answer will use the "How to Design Functions" "design recipe" [2]
and Racket's "Intermediate Student" language.

Follow these steps in sequence [3]:

```
                                                                     +------------+
                                                                     V            |
signature -> purpose -> examples -> stub -> template -> inventory -> test -> code +-> done
```

To develop "(filter predicate alist)":

1. *Signature* (**types of arguments and result**): `(A -> Boolean) ListOfA -> ListOfA`
2. *Purpose* (**one line summary**): `produce list of As for which (predicate a) is true`
3. *Examples:*

```
    (filter even? '()) => '()
    (filter even? '(1) => '()
    (filter even? '(2) => '(2)
```

4. *Stub* (**choose good names for function and arguments**; "filter" can't be used because it is
   defined in Intermediate Student language and can't be redefined):

```
(define (a-filter pred? loa)
  '())
```

Turn first example into a test to check that stub is well-formed, run:

```
(check-expect (a-filter even? '()) '() )

Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.4 [cs].
Language: Intermediate Student.
The test passed!
>
```

(Run after any change to code)

5. *Template* (function with list argument, copied from library of templates):

```
(define (fn lox) ;; ListOfX -> Y
  ;; produce a Y from lox
  (cond
    [(empty? lox) ... ]
    [else (... (first lox) ... (fn (rest lox))) ]))
```

Edit template to use names, add argument(s), add signature and purpose:

```
(define (a-filter pred? loa) ;; (A -> Boolean) ListOfA -> ListOfA
  ;; produce As for which (pred? a) is true
  (cond
    [(empty? loa) ... ]
    [else (... (first loa) ... (a-filter pred? (rest loa))) ]))
```

6. *Inventory:*

```
  if    (to choose As to be included) 
  cons  (to produce list result)
```

7. *Test* (from examples):

```
(check-expect (a-filter even? '()) '() )
```

8. *Code* (using test):

```
(define (a-filter pred? loa) ;; (A -> Boolean) ListOfA -> ListOfA
  ;; produce As for which (pred? a) is true
  (cond
    [(empty? loa) '() ]
    [else (... (first loa) ... (a-filter pred? (rest loa))) ]))
```

Add the next test and adjust code to pass:

```
(check-expect (a-filter even? '(1)) '() )

(define (a-filter pred? loa) ;; (A -> Boolean) ListOfA -> ListOfA
  ;; produce As for which (pred? a) is true
  (cond
    [(empty? loa) '() ]
    [else (if (pred? (first loa))
              ...
              (a-filter pred? (rest loa))) ]))
```

Add the next test and adjust code to pass:

```
(check-expect (a-filter even? '(2)) '(2) )

(define (a-filter pred? loa) ;; (A -> Boolean) ListOfA -> ListOfA
  ;; produce As for which (pred? a) is true
  (cond
    [(empty? loa) '() ]
    [else (if (pred? (first loa))
              (cons (first loa) (a-filter pred? (rest loa)))
              (a-filter pred? (rest loa))) ]))
```

To develop "predicate":
   Signature: `(List Name Number) -> Boolean`
   Purpose:   `produce whether number greater than 50`
   Example:   `(number>50? '(name 51)) => #t`

(choose names, Test and Code directly from signature and purpose):

```
(check-expect (number>50? '(name 50)) #f)
(check-expect (number>50? '(name 51)) #t)

(define (number>50? lnn) ;; (List Name Number) -> Boolean
  ;; produce whether number greater than 50
  (> (second lnn) 50))
```

Test use of predicate by `a-filter`:

```
(check-expect (a-filter number>50? '((name 50))) '() )
(check-expect (a-filter number>50? '((name 51))) '((name 51)) )

(check-expect (a-filter number>50? '((n1 50) (n2 51) (n3 -1) (n4 51))) '((n2 51) (n4 51)) )

Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.4 [cs].
Language: Intermediate Student.
All 8 tests passed!
>
```

[1]: An "alist" in Scheme is usually a list of pairs, eg `'((n1 . 50) (n2 . 51))` (an association list),
but this answer interprets an alist as a list of 2-element lists.
[2]: Descriptions of this systematic program development process can be found by searching for "How to Design Functions" "design recipe"
[3]: This may look like a lot to do before actual coding, but
when learning it may not be obvious how to start, even for a small function. The preparatory
steps (signature/purpose/examples/stub) can usually be done very quickly by extracting items
from the assignment text. The design process can work for more "difficult" functions, so is worth
practising on easy examples.